# AWS ECS with Docker Compose Files - "External" Docker Volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have existing `docker-compose.yml` file that runs on my Docker CE standalone server.

I would like to deploy this same configuration using the AWS ECS service. The documentation of the `ecs-cli` tool states that Docker Compose files can be used. Other (simpler) container configs have worked with my existing files.

With my configuration, this errors with:

> ERRO[0000] Unable to open ECS Compose Project error="External option
>   is not supported"
>
> FATA[0000] Unable to create and read ECS Compose Project 
>   error="External option is not supported"

I am using "external" Docker volumes, so that they are auto-generated as required and not deleted when a container is stopped or removed.

This is a simplification of the `docker-compose.yml` file I am testing with and would allow me to mount the volume to a running container:

```
version: '3'

services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox:1.31.1
    volumes:
      - ext_volume:/path/in/container

volumes:
  ext_volume:
    external: true
```

Alternatively, I have read in other documentation to use the `ecs-params.yml` file in the same directory to pass in variables. Is this a replacement to my `docker-compose.yml` file? I had expected to leave it's syntax unchanged.

Comment: When using the ecs-cli compose or ecs-cli compose service commands to manage your Amazon ECS tasks and services, there are certain fields in an Amazon ECS task definition that do not correspond to fields in a Docker compose file. You can specify those values using an ECS parameters file with the --ecs-params flag. By default, the command looks for an ECS parameters file in the current directory named ecs-params.yml.

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/927

Comment: Thanks @HumayunM. So I do have to use the ecs-params config instead of docker-compose. Not well documented that this 1 parameter cannot be maintained in the docker-compose config, as mentioned in the linked repo.

Comment: Thanks @LinPy, useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working config (this was ensuring the container stays running, so I could ssh in and view the mounted drive):

```
version: '3'

services:
  alpine:
    image: alpine:3.12
    volumes:
      - test_docker_volume:/path/in/container
    command:
      - tail 
      - -f 
      - /dev/null

volumes:
  test_docker_volume:
```

And in `ecs-params.yml`:

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  services:
    alpine:
      cpu_shares: 100
      mem_limit: 28000000
  docker_volumes:
    - name: test_docker_volume
      scope: "shared"
      autoprovision: true
```